# Python unittest discovery with subfolders

Tags: python, unit-testing

My unittest folder is organized this way.

```
.
|-- import
|   |-- import.kc
|   |-- import.kh
|   `-- import_test.py
|-- module
|   |-- module.kc
|   |-- module.kh
|   `-- module_test.py
`-- test.py
```

I'd want to simply run `test.py` to run each of my `*_test.py` using the *unittest* Python module.

Currently, my test.py contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('.', pattern = "*_test.py")
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

The python documentation says that it should automatically discover my test in the subfolders. But it does not.

At the moment, it only outputs

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I'm sure it is not a problem with my `*_test.py` file, because when I move them into the root directory, it works fine..
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Add `__init__.py` in the `import` and `module` directories.

Comment: It worked by just touching the `__init__.py` file, thanks you. Can you explain me why I have to do this ? And is there another solution wich ? Because I am working with other people, and I would like tests to be the easiest way possible to create.

Comment: This is an artifact of the way test discovery is implemented.  Essentially, each directory that contains a test has to be importable as a Python module.  See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) for more information.

Comment: From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) it says that namespace packages should be supported since 3.4, but I found that `__init__.py` is still needed. Why?

Comment: Struggled for a while till I found this. Thank you. Another nuance of the Python world.

Comment: in my scenario, my test file (`test.py`) was also in a sub directory. I needed to add `__init__.py` into that folder as well as `import` and `module` folders and then it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [nose2](https://docs.nose2.io/en/latest/) instead of the vanilla `unittest` module, if you are able to switch. You won't need to mess around with your own test.py file or anything; a run of `nosetests` will find and run all your tests.

Answer (score -1):

`python -m unittest tests/**_test.py`