# unittest is not able to discover / run tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import, nose, python-unittest

There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12674167/647991) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7728371/647991) questions, but none apply.

This is my directory tree:

```
» tree abc_backend
abc_backend/
├── backend_main.py
├── FundDatabase.db
├── healthcheck.py
├── __init__.py
├── init.py
├── portfolio.py
├── private.py
├── __pycache__
├── questionnaire.py
├── recurring.py
├── registration.py
├── tests
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── test_backend.py
│   ├── test_healthcheck.py
│   └── test_private.py
├── trading.py
├── Users.db
├── VERSION
└── visualisation.py
```

`unittest` is not able to find anything:

```
top » python -m unittest abc_backend

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Not even from within `abc_backend`:

```
abc_backend » python -m unittest tests

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

What I have already verified:

- my test methods are properly named (`test_whatever`)
- my testcases extend `unittest.TestCase`
- the `abc_backend` and the `abc_backend/tests` directories have an (empty) `__init__.py`
- all test modules are importable (see below)
- `unittest discover` finds the tests, but has problems with relative imports (see below)
- `nose` is able to discover and run the tests, no problems

I would like to understand:

- why do I need to pass `discover` to `unittest` to force it to discover the tests? What does `unittest` do without the `discover` sub-command? (I thought unittest does test discovery by default). According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#test-discovery):

> python -m unittest is the equivalent of python -m unittest discover

- once the tests are discovered (by forcing the `discover` sub-command), why do I have import issues?

### Test modules are importable

```
» python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import abc_backend.tests
>>> import abc_backend.tests.test_private
>>> import abc_backend.tests.test_healthcheck
>>> import abc_backend.tests.test_backend
```

### unittest discover has problems with relative imports

If I run it from the top dir:

```
top » python -m unittest discover abc_backend
======================================================================
ERROR: tests.test_private (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 577, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 32, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.test_private
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 312, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/foo/bar/abc_backend/tests/test_private.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .. import init
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

If I run it from within `abc_backend`:

```
abc_backend » python -m unittest discover tests

======================================================================
ERROR: test_private (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 577, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 32, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_private
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 312, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/foo/bar/abc_backend/tests/test_private.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .. import init
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Answer (score 9):

I reproduced all the problems with CPython 3.5, so my answer should
be relevant to both 3.4 and 3.5.

### Relative import issues

The reason why there are issues with relative imports is that due to
specifics of invocations you really do not import `abc_backend` package.

First, let’s take a look at

```
top» python3 -m unittest discover abc_backend
```

When you run tests from top that way, `abc_backend` is just not imported.
That is because `/home/user/top/abc_backend` is added to sys.path instead
of `/home/user/top`. To solve this problem, do

```
top» python3 -m unittest discover abc_backend -t .
```

Now, about the in-abc_backend invocation. When you do

```
abc_backend» python3 -m unittest discover tests
```

`abc_backend` is not importable, as `/home/user/top/abc_backend/tests`
dir does not contain `abc_backend` package. This too can be solved with

```
abc_backend» python3 -m unittest discover tests -t ../
```

that will correctly put `/home/user/top` dir (pun intended) into `sys.path`.

The `-t` (or `--top-level-directory`) option sets top level directory
of project and defaults to start directory (which is `.` by default).
So, what is in `sys.path` is important, as that affects imports, which
affect test loading, as discovery loads tests using import machinery.

### Difference between `-m unittest` and `-m unittest discover`

When you do

```
top» python3 -m unittest abc_backend
```

in reality you are running `unittest/__main__.py` file. There
`main(module=None)` is invoked, and eventually you get to
`loadTestsFromModule` that does

```
tests = []
for name in dir(module):
    obj = getattr(module, name)
    if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, case.TestCase):
        tests.append(self.loadTestsFromTestCase(obj))
```

As `abc_backend/__init__.py` does not contain any test cases,
`isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, case.TestCase)` returns
`False` for all module members (so `tests` is empty).

To make this particular way of invocation work, you’ll have to do
what people usually did in pre-`discover` times (aside from non-stdlib
frameworks): manually import cases from test modules (or
maybe construct test suite according to `load_tests` protocol).

So, how

```
top» python3 -m unittest discover abc_backend
```

differs?

Basically, differences may be expressed as following conditional:

```
if len(argv) > 1 and argv[1].lower() == 'discover':
    # -m unittest discover
    loader.discover(...)
else:
    # -m unittest
    loader.loadTestsFromNames(...)
```

When `argv` is `['python3 -m unittest', 'discover', 'abc_backend']`,
actual discovery mechanism is used. When `argv` is `['python3 -m unittest', 'abc_backend']`,
`loadTestsFromNames` is used, which calls `loadTestsFromModule` at some point, and no tests are found.
That’s the way things are in `unittest/main.py`.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered similar problem today, actually the solution was written in the [Python API document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover):

> If a package (a directory containing a file named **init**.py) is found, the package will be checked for a load_tests function. If this exists then it will be called package.load_tests(loader, tests, pattern). Test discovery takes care to ensure that a package is only checked for tests once during an invocation, even if the load_tests function itself calls loader.discover.

Hence, all you need to do is write a load_tests function and register your TestCase classes in __init__.py